# CSS Not Working When Inserted By PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have been trying to use PHP to insert my CSS's file contents in the `style` tag of a page.

```
<style>
    <?php 
        $css = file_get_contents('css/roboto-robotocondensed.css');
        $css .= file_get_contents('css/reset.css');
        $css .= file_get_contents('css/mainstyle.css');
        $css .= file_get_contents('css/industriaalimentosebebidas.css');
        echo $css;
    ?>
</style>
```

And in the last file, "industriaalimentosebebidas.css", i have the following code:

```
header {
    height: 500px; 
    background: url(../img/cases/casos-de-sucesso-alimentos-e-bebidas-cover.jpg) no-repeat center bottom / cover;
}

header p { 
    width: 75%;
    font-size: 1.536rem;
}
.imgGradient {
    height: 100%;
} 

@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    header {
        height: 700px;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the header style code above the media query is being ignored by the browser.
But, when I get the CSS file using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/industriaalimentosebebidas.css"/>
```

everything works fine.

In the inspector, the header height does not seem to be overwritten... and background image is not being loaded.

Even if I remove the media query part, the header part does not work.

In the html `head` I'm using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Does anyone have a clue of what might be going on?

Comment: Can you add the resulting page source code on the client side ? I mean view the source code from the browser, copy and paste it here - maybe it will be easier to see where's the problem

Comment: do you have it online somewhere? I guess one of the other files does not close a {

Comment: You can see it here
http://www.instrumentos-lince.com.br/industria-alimenticia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your css look for the line:

```css
#infos .imgContainer{max-height:25vw}1rem}
```

this is the reason it is broken.

**original:**

basically add spaces between the files: (not semicolons, remembered that wrong)

```
<style>
<?php 
    echo implode("\n", [
        file_get_contents('css/roboto-robotocondensed.css'),
        file_get_contents('css/reset.css'),
        file_get_contents('css/mainstyle.css'),
        file_get_contents('css/industriaalimentosebebidas.css')
    ]);
?>
</style>
```

Comment: no idea if this is applicable to *this* problem but sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: Adding semicolons actually breaks the CSS, because of media queries closing brackets.

But removing that 1rem solved the problem. 
For some reason when I minified the CSS it got broke.

Thanks!